# Region of convergence in Inverse laplace transform

Tags: integral-transforms

Lets say we have a function in the s domain. Let it be H(s)=1/(s+1). It has one pole.

If we consider the region to the right of the pole as the ROC, we would one function in the time domain when we use the inverse laplace transform on H(s),this time function would be a right sided function.
If we consider the region to the left of the pole as the ROC, we will get another time function. This time function would be a left sided function.

The difference arises due the selection of different ROCs.The InverseLaplaceTransform function in Mathematica 11 seems to by default take the ROC to the right of the pole.I am not able to find a method the change the default ROC.

Is there a method to change the region of convergence when using the InverseLaplaceTransform[ ] function?

Comment: If you give a concrete example, you are more likely to get a helpful answer

Comment: @mikado I have added some more information. Kindly tell me if this information is sufficient to understand my question.

Comment: that is a much better question